# Practical LabVIEW-free Keithley 2400 front-end for Linux?

Tags: linux, test-equipment

Is there a high quality LabVIEW-free gui/interface/front-end to communicate with Keithley 2400 on Linux? Not just for single measurements, but also for various sweeps for practical daily use?

Answer (score 1):

There is PyVISA for HPIB/GPIB instrument reading.  This is a wrapper around the VISA dll from NI.

There is a new effort PyVISA-py which replaces that VISA DLL.

It's a shame that most higher end instruments that you need to use in design almost certainly needs LabView.

Comment: But with PyVISA I'd still have to write my own front-end...

Comment: @Sparkler It's not *that* hard, I've done it myself.